# Login Issues with Oracle databases

Tags: windows-7, oracle-10g

I had to setup an Oracle environment. The stage is as follows: there are Oracle 11.2 client and 10g express server, the OS is Windows 7, 64-bit. I have the ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID and PATH env. variables set correctly.

I have to connect to the server via the 11.2 client.

When I type in cmd:

1. sqlplus, then
2. username, then
3. password

I get ORA-12560 and after 3 attempts I get disconnected.

but if I type the following:

```
sqplplus username/password@xe
```

I get connected without any further objection from Oracle.

Have you had similar experience? Do you have an idea why this behavior is exhibited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-12560

ORA-12560 is [TNS Protocol adapter error](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:431775600346873836) which happens if the TNS listener service is incorrectly configured or not running. When you type `sqlplus` and enter only the username & password, Oracle assumes the default TNS name of `orcl` which is not configured in your system.

When you type in

```
sqplplus username/password@xe
```

you're explicitly giving the TNS name as `xe` which is then resolved by looking up the `tnsnames.ora` file in `%oracle_home%\network\admin` directory and then connects to that instance of the database

Comment: Thank you! Can you just clarify what's orcl in "assumes the default TNS name of orcl"?

Comment: @karla orcl is the default name of the service for an Oracle instance, much like how xe is the name of the service in your case